# Ошибка в синтаксисе

Tags: jquery, синтаксис

Подскажите пожалуйста, где допустил ошибку?
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '(' in .......

Сам код:

```
     $(document).ready(function() <?php echo "#jpId".jPlayer.ready.function; ?>); - ошибка
    },
    supplied: "m4a, oga",
    swfPath: "/jPlayer/js"
  });
});
```

Comment: Что это за бред??

    <?php echo "#jpId".jPlayer.ready.function; ?>

Это явно к PHP никакого отношения не имеет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка не jquery, а php. Все, что вы эхаете, должно либо быть переменной со строкой и строкоприводимым объектом, либо заключено в кавычки. У вас же в кавычки взят только jpId, остальное воспринимается как константы, а function как объявление функции, которая и ожидает открывающую скобку.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {<?php echo '"#jpId".jPlayer.ready.function;' ?>);
    },
    supplied: "m4a, oga",
    swfPath: "/jPlayer/js"
  });
});
```

В принципе, этот код тоже не будет работать, но уже на стороне js, потому что я не знаю, что он должен делать, а в текущей версии это не будет валидным js.

Comment: Вообще это результат кеширования скрипта который выглядит вот так:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jpId").jPlayer( {
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "../mp3/elvis.mp3" 
      });
    }
  });
});

И результат кеширования заносится в файл:
frontend_nebula_template_template.html.php.php
В котором собственно и обнаруживается эта ошибка

Comment: @BIGsergik, кто писал код этого замечательного кэшера?

Comment: кэшер движка phpFOX

Comment: Может быть это конфликт со стандартными функциями?
Есть правило которое может это определить?
Странно, но сколько не пытаюсь ничего реализовать своего не получается..

Comment: @BIGsergik, этот кэшер можно выкидывать, если он делает такое из валидного файла. Никакого конфликта здесь нет, только кривой синтаксис.

Comment: А может быть я просто не там написал именно сам скрипт?
Может быть такое, что директория не предназначена для хранения файлов которые содержат в себе Javascript код? 
Сейчас проверил модули которые содержаться по дефолту в движке и действительно в подобных местах имеется только голый PHP

Comment: @BIGsergik, я не знаю что у вас за движок и что там внутри. Ответ можете дать только вы сами, если разберетесь, с чем и как работаете.

Answer (score 0):

Может все-таки имелось ввиду:

```
<?php echo '"#jpId".jPlayer.ready.function'; ?>
```

Comment: опоздал)))

Comment: Вообще это результат кеширования скрипта который выглядит вот так: $(document).ready(function() { $("#jpId").jPlayer( { ready: function () { $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "../mp3/elvis.mp3" }); } }); });
И результат кеширования заносится в файл: frontend_nebula_template_template.html.php.php В котором собственно и обнаруживается эта ошибка
В комментариях не могу отформатировать текст под код.